# Why do I get "Nothing to install or update" when I update to latest core version?

Tags: 8, composer

Under /admin/modules/update, Drupal core is listed as requiring update from 8.8.8 to 8.9.2. I have started my Drupal installation using the *drupal/recommended-project* project template and I used `composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies` to update Drupal core, but when I run the above command, all I get is this message.

> Nothing to install or update

Am I missing something?

This is the content of the composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/addtoany": "^1.14",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.3",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^4.0",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.1",
        "drupal/business_rules": "^1.0",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.1",
        "drupal/change_pwd_page": "^1.0",
        "drupal/colorbox": "^1.4",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
        "drupal/dynamic_entity_reference": "^1.10",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.8",
        "drupal/eva": "^2.1",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.0",
        "drupal/field_timer": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/firebase": "^2.0",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.16",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_checkboxradio": "^1.2",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6",
        "drupal/persistent_login": "^1.3",
        "drupal/reroute_email": "^1.2",
        "drupal/simple_fb_connect": "^3.1",
        "drupal/simplify": "^1.1",
        "drupal/sitewide_alert": "^1.3",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.2",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.3",
        "drupal/sms": "^1.3",
        "drupal/sms_simplegateway": "^1.1",
        "drupal/subpathauto": "^1.1",
        "drupal/telephone_validation": "^2.3",
        "drupal/token": "^1.6",
        "drupal/token_filter": "^1.1",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0",
        "drupal/video": "^1.4",
        "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.7",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.2",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        },        
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": ["homepage", "support"],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",

                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Update #1:**

I have updated my composer.json file from:

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
"drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
```

to:

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9",
"drupal/core-project-message": "^8.9",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9",
```

**But I got the below list of errors:**

```
user@example.com [~/public_html/test.example.com]# composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package drupal/core-dev (locked at 8.8.2, required as ^8.9) is satisfiable by drupal/core-dev[8.8.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.2 requires drupal/core 8.9.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.2
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1 requires drupal/core 8.9.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.1
    - Installation request for symfony/polyfill-php72 (locked at v1.17.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/polyfill-php72[v1.17.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0 requires drupal/core 8.9.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.0
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta3 requires symfony/polyfill-php72 v1.15.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/polyfill-php72[v1.15.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-rc1 requires symfony/polyfill-php72 v1.15.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/polyfill-php72[v1.15.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/polyfill-php72 v1.15.0
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta2 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-beta2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-beta2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.0-beta2
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.0-beta1 requires drupal/core 8.9.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0-beta1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.0-beta1
    - drupal/sms 1.3.0 requires drupal/core >=8.6 <8.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.8, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.18, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.10, 8.7.11, 8.7.12, 8.7.13, 8.7.14, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.9, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.x-dev].
    - drupal/sms 1.3.0 requires drupal/core >=8.6 <8.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.8, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.18, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.10, 8.7.11, 8.7.12, 8.7.13, 8.7.14, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.9, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.x-dev].
    - drupal/sms 1.3.0 requires drupal/core >=8.6 <8.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.8, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.18, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.10, 8.7.11, 8.7.12, 8.7.13, 8.7.14, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.9, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.x-dev].
    - drupal/sms 1.3.0 requires drupal/core >=8.6 <8.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.8, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.18, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.10, 8.7.11, 8.7.12, 8.7.13, 8.7.14, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.9, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.0-alpha1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.0-beta1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.3].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.4].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.5].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.6].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.7].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.8].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.0-alpha1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.0-beta1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.0-beta2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.10].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.11].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.12].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.13].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.14].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.15].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.16].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.17].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.18].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.3].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.4].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.5].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.7].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.8].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.6.9].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0-alpha1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0-alpha2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0-beta1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0-beta2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.1].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.10].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.11].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.12].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.13].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.14].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.2].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.3].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.4].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.5].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.6].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.7].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.8].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.9].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.8].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.x-dev, 8.8.8].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.x-dev requires drupal/core 8.9.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended ^8.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.9.0, 8.9.0-beta1, 8.9.0-beta2, 8.9.0-beta3, 8.9.0-rc1, 8.9.1, 8.9.2, 8.9.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal/sms (locked at 1.3.0, required as ^1.3) -> satisfiable by drupal/sms[1.3.0].
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I removed the `composer.lock` file and ran: `composer install` command!

A bunch of updates ran smoothly including `drupal/core-dev (8.8.2 => 8.9.2)`, but when I visit `/admin/reports/updates/update`, I still can see update avaialble for Drupal core (`Drupal core  8.8.8 -> 8.9.2`) also in the `composer.json` file, the Drupal version is still `"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8"` and in the
`composer.lock` file the Drupal version is:

```
"name": "drupal/core-recommended",
"version": "8.8.8",
"source": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/drupal/core-recommended.git",
"reference": "69f4e74170c35f2069baafbbb5b7717fe5ddbb66"
```

Note: After `composer install`, I did run `drush updb` and `drush cr`

[image: Update #2]

Comment: Did you try to remove composer.lock and run composer install again?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes I did try this but same list of errors and without new `composer.lock` file being generated.
Also `composer update` generated the same error while the `composer.lock`file is removed

Comment: Do not change the version in the composer.json file. Leave it as `^8.8` and then remove the composer.lock file and run `composer install`

Comment: @Ahmad I did remove the `composer.lock` file and kept the Drupal version `^8.8` then run `composer install` but still not working... Please check **Update #2** section of the question for more details. Thank you

Comment: Did you try removing composer.lock and vendor directory then updating?

Comment: the version will not be updated in composer.json but it should be updated in `composer.lock`.

Comment: Can you try `composer update drupal/core`?

Comment: @Ahmad when I run `composer update drupal/core` I received `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: @edg I did removed both `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file then I run `composer install` and I noticed the command `Installing drupal/core-dev (8.9.2)` running but same happened as explained in **Update #2** section of the question.
Also both `composer.` files have the same `8.8.8` Drupal version !
I can't find a solution for this problem

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change the following lines of your `composer.json`

```
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
```

with

```
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.9",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9",
```

As the current settings constraints the drupal/core to 8.8.x version.

Comment: Can you please check the update to my question ?
Your suggestion did not work well for me

Comment: Did you manage ? This is the command I used : ```composer update drupal/core drupal/core-recommended drupal/core-composer-scaffold drupal/core-project-message drupal/core-vendor-hardening --with-dependencies```

Comment: @SimonVart , `^8.8` also allows for installation of `8.9.x`, so that shouldn't matter.